# Problem with wp_list_categories

Tags: categories

I use `wp_list_categories('echo=true&show_count=1')`. Everything works well but there is one thing is that. Show category contains 1 post, but it results count is zero, I click on that category link, I can see that one post. Similarly, if I have categories whose 10 posts, it show count value is 9 only...
Any suggestion for this? Thanks.

Comment: Disable all of your plugins one by one and switch to a default theme. Do you still have this issue?

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but it will ruin all mine. Maybe I will re-render the list in manual way.

Comment: If you are unwilling to do any debugging I wish you the best.